# How do I pass parameters to a callback function for a timer interrupt on Arduino?

Tags: timer, callback, arduino, interrupt

I want a timer interrupt to call a function with a set of parameters on an Arduino. I have looked at the Timer1 library, but it seems unable to be used in a way to pass parameters to the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You'll have to use some sort of global struct to save your current state. When the callback is used, get the data you need from that struct.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your callback into a parameterless function. This wrapper function can pass whatever parameters you want into your function.